# Is it possible to swap out the Node.js net socket data event listener?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, callback

I'm using the Node.js [net](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html) package to connect to and communicate with a Telnet server. I'm using `net.createConnection()` to create and initialize a socket; then doing something like the following to bind the initial data event listener:

`client.on('data', (data) => { this.handleFoo(data) });`

I thought it might be a good idea to encapsulate different functionality in different callbacks; one  to handle negotiating the connection, logging in, etc. One for general purpose communication.

I tried simply calling `.on()` again to see if I could replace the event listener callback to something that didn't have all of the connection/logon code:

`client.on('data', (data) => { this.handleBar(data) });`

Unfortunately that had no effect, and the original callback was getting called again. Is this possible to do?

I couldn't find another socket method that would un-register that first listener callback.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need a named function. Use [`client.removeListener()`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_removelistener_eventname_listener) or [`client.off()`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_off_eventname_listener) available since Node.js v10.0.0. These are available to [`net.Socket`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket) because it extends [`EventEmitter`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter).

```
const fooHandler = (data) => { this.handleFoo(data) };

client.on('data', fooHandler);
...
client.off('data', fooHandler);
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick! I'll give this a try when I get home, and if it works I'll mark your answer as correct :)